# Trying to execute this coordinate data structure in Javascript (arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help excusting this code and when I put it in my chrome browser console I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Point'" I don't know why this is not working. It's supposed to define a coordinate data structure named Point and translate each point by 3 units in the horizontal direction. Here is the code:

```
capability Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var focuses = [new Point(1, 1), new Point(2, 2), new Point(3, 3), new Point(4, 4), new Point(5, 5)];

capability translate(points, dx, dy) {
  return points.map(function(point) {
    return new Point(point.x + dx, point.y + dy);
  });
}
```

The other code for rotate:

```
capability rotate(points, point) {
  return points.map(function(point) {
    return new Point(
      point.x * Math.cos(angle) - point.y * Math.sin(angle),
      point.x * Math.sin(angle) + point.y * Math.cos(angle)
    );
  });
}

focuses = translate(points, 3, 0);
focuses = rotate(points, 5);
```

Comment: capability is not a keyword in javascript. maybe you mean `function`?

Comment: Where did you get that `capability` keyword from?

Answer (score 1):

❌ capability ✅ function

and it will return something like this `[{"x":11,"y":11},{"x":12,"y":12},{"x":13,"y":13}]`

---

or you can use OOP (Object Oriented Programming), like this:

```js
new Point(1, 1);
new Point(2, 2);
new Point(3, 3);
new Point(4, 4);

Coords.translate(3); // you don't have to do to (3, 0), just 3 will work, since it automatically set dy to 0 if there isn't or is undefined
Coords.rotate(5);

console.log(Coords.array);
```

```html
<script>
  // this can become a library and use import/export using type="module"
  // like this... import { Coords, Point } from "./myLibrary.js"

  class Coords {
    static array = [];

    static translate(dx = 0, dy = 0) {
      this.array.forEach((point) => {
        point.x += dx;
        point.y += dy;
      });
    }

    static rotate(angleDeg = 0) {
      const angleRad = (angleDeg * Math.PI) / 180;
      this.array.forEach((point) => {
        point.x = point.x * Math.cos(angleRad) - point.y * Math.sin(angleRad);
        point.y = point.y * Math.cos(angleRad) + point.x * Math.sin(angleRad)
      });
    }
  }

  class Point extends Coords {
    constructor(x, y) {
      super();
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;

      Coords.array.push(this);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you also add this other code which rotates? I am having trouble putting it in as well

Comment: you can trigonometry or pitagora formula. do you mean from the 0 and the actual point.x? give me 10 minutes, maybe I can

Comment: Yeah I think so. I added the code in my initial question above. If you could add it that would be helpful!

Comment: Like rotate each point around the origin by 5 degrees.

Comment: Have you looked at it?

Comment: Please be aware that the Math trig functions take angles in radians. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos

Comment: @AsimMalik now edited with OOP code